# Change C indent style for specific project?

Tags: init-file, c++, c, project

I have in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(use-package google-c-style
  ;; provides the Google C/C++ coding style
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-set-c-style))
```

However, a particular C project I'm viewing uses

```
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)
```

How can I override the default google C style with this one for this specific project? Something along the lines of putting something inside of `.dir-locals.el` placed at the root of the project would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A .dir-locals.el file would certainly do the trick!

I like to use the function `(add-dir-local-variable MODE VARIABLE VALUE)` rather editing .dir-locals.el manually.  For those two values eval

```
(let ((default-directory "~/your/project/path"))
     (add-dir-local-variable nil 'c-default-style "linux")
     (add-dir-local-variable nil 'c-basic-offset 4))
```

and save the created .dir-locals.el file!

Comment: I don't understand the approach here - where do I put these 3 lines such that a .dir-locals.el is generated?

Comment: @space_voyager One way to eval the expression is by putting the cursor after the last closing parentheses and press `C-x C-e`. You can do this from nearly any buffer (you could paste the code into *scratch* for example). Once you've run the code above you don't need it anymore since the code creates the .dir-locals.el file. Be sure to save the new .dir-locals.el file that emacs opens when it is run.

Comment: `(put 'c-default-style 'safe-local-variable #'stringp)`